# How to get 2 maximum id from table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have many records in my table.I want to fetch 2 records which should have maximum or second last maximum id value .How will i do this in mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT FROM [table] WHERE [condition] ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: what will be condition i can't use aggregate function.

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar: if you need to filter data you use `WHERE ...`, else you can strip that part from query

Comment: In that case you can skip the condition, it would just be `SELECT FROM [table] ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2`